# How to restrict the query params in post method in Spring Rest Api?

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc

How to restrict the query params in post method in Spring Rest Api?

URL: http://localhost:9003/test-api/getDetails

RequestBody:

```
{
  "name": "TestUser",
  "age": 25,
  "Email": "abc@test.com"

}
```

In the above URL, if there is get query params as below , we should throw error/ restrict
http://localhost:9003/test-api/getDetails?dateOfBirth=26081992

My Code:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/getDetails", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = "application/json;charset=UTF-8")
public @ResponseBody ResponseEntity<String> TestMethod(
            @Valid @RequestBody CustomerDetails customerDetails, BindingResult result,
             HttpServletRequest request) {
             //..some Actions
             }
```

Comment: why? you control what parameters are used in the controller, regardless of what the user does.

Comment: Do you when doing POST or GET?

Comment: Why don't you simply *ignore* the query parameters?

Comment: @EssexBoy  That's right .. but can we throw an error in this case if the user is sending query params which is not required for the app (it just ignores)..??

Comment: @CássioMazzochiMolin Yes we can, But In my scenario , I need to handle/retrict it and throw error

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could bind all query parameters to a [`Map<String, String>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) or [`MultiValueMap<String, String>`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/util/MultiValueMap.html) using [`@RequestParam`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestParam.html). From the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestParam.html):

> If the method parameter is  [`Map<String, String>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) or [`MultiValueMap<String, String>`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/util/MultiValueMap.html) and a parameter name is not specified, then the map parameter is populated with all request parameter names and values.

Something like:

```java
@RequestMapping(value = "/foo", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ResponseEntity<String> foo(@RequestParam Map<String, String> requestParams,
                                  @RequestBody Foo foo) {
    ...     
}
```

Then refuse the request with a `400` status code if the map contains invalid values.